# Convert string with thousands (and decimal) separator into double

Tags: c++, parsing

User can enter `double` into textbox. Number might contain thousands separators. I want to validate user input, before inserting entered number into database.

Is there a C++ function that can convert such input (`1,555.99`) into `double`? If there is, can it signal error if input is invalid (I do not want to end up with function similar to `atof`)?

Something like [`strtod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtod/), but must accept input with thousands separators.

Comment: Do note that the use of a comma as a thousands separator is locale-specific.  Other locales may use different (even seemingly backwards) conventions: [Decimal and Thousands Separators](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/806-0169/overview-9/index.html)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart most other European languages uses `.` or space as thousand separator and `,` as decimal separator

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert the input to double using a stream that's been imbued with a locale that accepts thousand separators.

```
#include <locale>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    double d;

    std::cin.imbue(std::locale(""));
    std::cin >> d;

    std::cout << d;
}
```

Here I've used the un-named locale, which retrieves locale information from the environment (e.g., from the OS) and sets an appropriate locale (e.g., in my case it's set to something like `en_US`, which supports commas as thousands separators, so:

```
Input: 1,234.5
Output: 1234.5
```

Of course, I could also imbue `std::cout` with some locale that (for example) uses a different thousands separator, and get output tailored for that locale (but in this case I've used the default "C" locale, which doesn't use thousands separators, just to make the numeric nature of the value obvious).

When you need to do this with something that's already "in" your program as a string, you can use an `std::stringstream` to do the conversion:

```
std::string input = "1,234,567.89";

std::istringstream buffer(input);
buffer.imbue(std::locale(""));

double d;
buffer >> d;
```

Comment: I have successfully set locale, and textbox is subclassed to allow only valid thousands/decimal separator to be typed in. All that is taken care of. I take the input from textbox, *not from `cin`* and that is the cause of my confusion regarding your answer -> how would I apply your solution to a string *filled with input from textbox?* Something like `std::string s = 1,555.22` `//code for conversion`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff: See edited answer for an example using `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 1):

A C solution would be to use setlocale & sscanf:

```
const char *oldL = setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "de_DE.UTF-8");
double d1 = 1000.43, d2 = 0;
sscanf("1.000,43", "%'lf", &d2);
if ( std::abs(d1-d2) < 0.01 )
  printf("OK \n");
else
  printf("something is wrong! \n");
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, oldL);
```