# How to read a number with commas from a file in C++?

Tags: c++

Basically, I know how to read a number from a CSV file. But now a number that I've got to read has a different structure. Until now my numbers weren't separated by commas:

```
1000000;
```

I have to read a number that looks like that:

```
1,000,000;
```

In both examples, there are the same numbers (million). In the second one, the commas are there for better visibility.

So my question is, how can I read that number and save it to an integer?
I thought that I should use RegEx, but I'm not good with it, so it's just an idea.

Comment: s/,//g \\ .....

Comment: My approach would be to have a single entity like `1,000,000;` in a `std::string` and using `std::copy_if` and a lambda you can how it copy only the characters that are valid for you. 


`[](const char c) { return c != ',' && c != ';'; }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string with thousands (and decimal) separator into double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470656/convert-string-with-thousands-and-decimal-separator-into-double)

Comment: Check [`std::locale`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) please.

Comment: As I see it, your *actual* question is about how to do [parsing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) and writing a parser.

Comment: Writing your own parser for standard representations of standard data types is rarely required. C++ Standard Library supplies enough tools to make it possible without custom code. Unfortunately, it's not always done in the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use locale to process thousands separator, like this:

```
std::cin.imbue(std::locale(""));
int k;
std::cin >> k;
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/9PbYcs)

Comment: So I've created a file and write there: **1,234,567**. It only shows me in console number one (1). [Here's](https://ideone.com/zKrUwC) my code.

Comment: @wolnio `imbue` needs to run on the stream from which you read. In your case it would be `file`, so change line 6 to `file.imbue(std::locale(""));`